# Net Maui how can i bind clicked value?

Tags: maui

```
                   <Button Text="test" Clicked="{Binding Metodo}"/>
```

Goal: run anything [different method] when click boxview or imagebutton
i have a CollectionView with boxvie,label and imagebutton, i want items clicked=[string binded]
but clicked is not bindable?

I'm starting to learn c# and net maui, but I wanted to create a menu using collectionview, and inserting what I want into it, but I discovered that I don't know how to perform different actions based on the child clicked in the collectionview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ES_Restic_Dominator.MainPage"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:m="clr-namespace:UraniumUI.Icons.MaterialIcons;assembly=UraniumUI.Icons.MaterialIcons"                 
             BackgroundImageSource="sfondo1.jpg" Title="Es Restic Dominator" >

    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"  VerticalOptions="Center" >
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <BoxView Color="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" CornerRadius="20" Opacity="0.7"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Metodo}"/>
                    <ImageButton Source="{Binding Immagine}" Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
                    <Button Text="test" Clicked="{Binding Metodo}">
                       
                    </Button>


                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Spacing="5" >
                        <Label Text="{Binding Nome}" FontSize="Title" TextColor="{StaticResource Gray950}" Padding="50,20,20,0"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Descrizione}" FontSize="Body" TextColor="{StaticResource Gray600}" Padding="50,0,0,0" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

```
using ES_Restic_Dominator.Views;

namespace ES_Restic_Dominator
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Descrizione { get; set; }
        public string Immagine { get; set; }
        public string Metodo { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {


        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Esempio di dati
            var items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Nome = "Doc. Restic", Descrizione = "Documentazione Restic", Immagine = "appunti.png", Metodo = "Doc" },
            new Item { Nome = "Snapshots", Descrizione = "Elenca tutti gli snapshots", Immagine = "cloud.png", Metodo = "Snapshots" },
            new Item { Nome = "Download", Descrizione = "Scarica tutti i Repository", Immagine = "discore.png", Metodo = "Download" },
            new Item { Nome = "Check", Descrizione = "Check di tutti i Repository", Immagine = "cuore.png", Metodo = "Check" },
            // Aggiungi altri elementi come necessario
        };

            collectionView.ItemsSource = items;
        }

        private async void Doc(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Doc());
            await DisplayAlert("Doc", "Doc", "OK");
        }
        private async void Snapshots(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Snapshots", "Snapshots", "OK");
        }

        private async void Download(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Download", "Download", "OK");
        }

        private async void Check(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Check", "Check", "OK");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Clicked is an event.  You can only bind Commands.  Or you can use EventToCommandBehavior to translate events into commands

Comment: The problem is `Clicked="{Binding Metodo}"`. To set `Clicked` it needs to refer to a Click event handler. Perhaps you wanted to keep it as `Clicked=Check` but then assign `{Binding Methodo}` to `CommandParameter` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```cs
SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/collectionview/?tabs=vswin&tutorial-step=3